# Why next(a) giving error while next(ia) returning first element of the list in Python?

Tags: python, list, iterator, listiterator

```
    >>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    >>> iter(a)
   <listiterator object at 0x7f96f3273950>
   >>> next(a)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: list object is not an iterator
   >>> ia=iter(a)
   >>> next(a)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     TypeError: list object is not an iterator
  >>> next(ia)
       1
```

Why next(a) giving error while next(ia) returning first element of the list in Python? Why it is happening?

Comment: Is there something in the error message `TypeError: list object is not an iterator` that you don't understand?

Comment: yes @EdChum can you tell me

Answer (score 3):

It's literally because of what the exception is telling you:

> list object is not an iterator

To be able to iterate over a sequence you need to have a current location and a list has no concept of this because that would mean that everyone who shares the list would also share the current location.

An iterator on the other hand is specific to a certain scope and keeps track of the current location. When you request an iterator from a list you'll get a new one every time.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> ia = iter(a)
>>> ia2 = iter(a)
>>> ia is ia2
False
>>> next(ia)
1
>>> next(ia2)
1
```

As you can see, *ia* and *ia2* have independent current locations because they are different iterators.

To illustrate why we need this, here's an example that uses two loops to iterate over the same list:

```
>>> for i in a:
...     print("{}:".format(i))
...     for j in a:
...             print("\t{}".format(j))
... 
1:
        1
        2
        3
2:
        1
        2
        3
3:
        1
        2
        3
```

This works because every for loop uses a separate iterator.

If we instead make them use the same iterator we get very different results:

```
>>> a = iter(a)
>>> for i in a:
...     print("{}:".format(i))
...     for j in a:
...             print("\t{}".format(j))
... 
1:
        2
        3
```

This time, both iterators share the current location and as such we will only iterate over the list one time, regardless of the fact that the loops are nested.